# Confusion about finite differences (of polynomials)

Tags: polynomials

I am currently trying to understand the given [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptW5v.png) to this problem:

> The polynomial P of n-th degree is such that, for each i=0,1,…,n, P(i) equals the remainder of i modulo 2. Evaluate P(n+1).

I understand the last part of the solution, however I do not see how they have arrived that the conclusion that

> $P^{[i]}(x)=(−2)^{i−1}(−1)^x$  for $x=0,1,…,n−i$

($P^{[i]}$ being the $i^{th}$ difference).

I have tried to reach their expression with the general formula for finite differences:
$$P^{[k]}=\sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{k-i}\binom ki P(x+i).$$
But I have not gotten very far with it. Could someone explain to me how this conclusion is reached?

Comment: If one sets up the difference table and manually calculate terms, then that conclusion is almost immediately noticeable. Can you write up the difference table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one sets up the difference table and manually calculate terms, then that conclusion is almost immediately noticeable. Can you write up the difference table?

> [image]

Now, if you want a proof of the conclusion (instead of just taking it at face value), induction works easily.
If you have trouble, show your work.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that :)